# User.find_for_oauth - where can I find it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm studying Devise + omniauth.
In most examples I find method User.find_for_oauth

Where can I find docs for this method & its ins and outs?
Is it provided by Devise or omniauth gems?

[here](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) and [here](http://www.thoughtsonrails.com/devise-and-omniauth/) are some examples where I came across it.

Answer (score 0):

The User.find_for_oauth() isn't provided by Devise or Omniauth.  It's something you have to provide.

Have another look at the examples in the links you gave.  They show code for find_for_auth.    The first link has it in the app/models/user.rb code in the Basic Implementation section.  The second has it in an ActiveRecordHelpers class which they include in their User model.