# Rails on Neo4j, using Devise -> undefined method `find_for_oauth' for Neo4j

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Running rails 4.2.6, ruby 2.3.1p112 with Neo4j Community edition.
On callback from Facebook I get this error:
undefined method `find_for_oauth' for Neo4j::Shared::Identity:Module
On models/user.rb:

```
identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
```

My files are as such:
models/user.rb

```
    class User 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_one :both, :identity, model_class: 'Identity', type: :has
  has_many :both, :friends, model_class: 'User', type: :friends

  property :username, type: String
  property :facebook_token, type: String
  index :facebook_token
  property :created_at, type: DateTime
  property :updated_at, type: DateTime
  property :logged_out, type: DateTime

  ## Database authenticatable
  property :email, type: String, null: false, default: ""
  index :email

  property :encrypted_password

  ## If you include devise modules, uncomment the properties below.

  ## Rememberable
  property :remember_created_at, type: DateTime
  property :remember_token
  index :remember_token


  ## Recoverable
  property :reset_password_token
  index :reset_password_token
  property :reset_password_sent_at, type: DateTime

  ## Trackable
  property :sign_in_count, type: Integer, default: 0
  property :current_sign_in_at, type: DateTime
  property :last_sign_in_at, type: DateTime
  property :current_sign_in_ip, type:  String
  property :last_sign_in_ip, type: String

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  property :name, type: String
  property :email, type: String
  property :username, type: String

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    if user.nil?

      email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified
      user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

      # Create the user if it's a new registration
      if user.nil?
        user = User.new(
            name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
            #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
            email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
            password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        )
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
      end
    end

    # Associate the identity with the user if needed
    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end
    user
  end
end
```

models/identity.rb

```
class Identity 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :provider, type: String
  property :uid, type: String

  has_one :in_or_out_or_both, :user, type: :owner

  validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
    find_or_create_by(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider)
  end

end
```

routes.rb (well the interesting part of it)

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
as :user do
    get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    match 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session,
          :via => Devise.mappings[:user].sign_out_via
end
```

Callback from Facebook is this:

```
flash: {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"alert"=>"Could not authenticate you from Facebook because \"Invalid credentials\"."}}
```

This is ok for now - just need to fix the "undefined method" problem.
I'm thinking it's the user->identity relation that's whack, but haven't been successful finding another/the right way to do it.

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: are you following a tutorial or something? Where is `find_for_oauth` **supposed** to be defined?

Comment: Well, yes - using a devise tutorial, though it's not for Neo4j-use, so maybe barking up the wrong tree. Haven't used devise before.
find_for_oauth is supposed to be in Identity-model - have tried with a helper, but no luck.
Still tinkering with it...

Comment: I really think this has nothing to do with Neo4j. Are you sure the tutorial doesn't include a step to define the method? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598220/user-find-for-oauth-where-can-i-find-it

Comment: Neo4j is in all other regards working fine, however found a problem in my relations in Identity model:
has_one :in_or_out_or_both, :user, model_class: 'User', type: :authentication
Needed the model_class: parameter
Problem persists though...
Also facebook signs in allright, so dies on callback